# extracting information from a text using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to extract some information from a text file.This is a line in my text file and I want to extract the numbers and save these numbers in an array.

```
ST/X   1000.0000000000000000   1400.0000000000000000   40.0000000000000000   25.0000000000000000   12.0000000000000000
```

The number of numbers are not fix(i.e in this example I have 5 numbers but it could be more or less)
There are always 3 spaces between the numbers, but the length of numbers also are not fix(for example 1000.0000000000000000 has a length of 21, but 12.0000000000000000 has a length of 19). I wrote this block of code. but the problem of my code is that it returns the white space as the last number too. my code doesnt work correctly 
Did you have a better Idea for me to do this job better?
thank you for your helps and ideas :)

my code:

```
 Dim lngPos As Long 
 Dim lngCount As Long 
 Dim ifile As Integer 
 Dim Xarray() As String 
 Let ifile = FreeFile 
 Dim Name As String 
 Dim xi As Integer 
 Name = util1.fDateiName("*.txt", "Text") 
'"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\bbastan\Desktop\test.txt" 
'Open Name For Input As ifile 

'While Not EOF(ifile) 
'Line Input #ifile, entireline 
ReDim Xarray(10) 
xi = 0 
Open Name For Input As ifile 
lngPos = 1 
While Not EOF(ifile) 
Line Input #ifile, entireline 

       Do 
        lngPos = InStr(lngPos, entireline, Space(3)) 
        If lngPos > 0 Then 
            xi = xi + 1 
            lngCount = lngCount + 1 
            lngPos = lngPos + 3 
            Xarray(xi) = Mid(entireline, lngPos, 21) 
        End If 
    Loop Until lngPos = 0 
Wend 

Dim I As Integer 
If xi > 2 Then 
MsgBox "ja" 
For I = 1 To xi - 1 
MsgBox Xarray(I) 
Next I 
Else 
MsgBox "nein" 
For I = 1 To xi 
MsgBox Xarray(I) 
Next I
```

Comment: You could use a [Split function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.80).aspx) instead and set your separator as 3 white spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA `Split()` function might simplify things for you somewhat. It splits a string using a delimiter and puts the elements into an array. For example, the following test code...

```
Sub LineSplitTest()
Dim entireline As String, strArray() As String, thing As Variant
entireline = "ST/X   1000.0000000000000000   1400.0000000000000000   40.0000000000000000   25.0000000000000000   12.0000000000000000  "
strArray = Split(entireline, Space(3), -1, vbBinaryCompare)
For Each thing In strArray
    thing = Trim(thing)
    If Len(thing) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print thing
    End If
Next
Debug.Print "[done]"
End Sub
```

...prints this in the Immediate Window of the VBA IDE:

```
ST/X
1000.0000000000000000
1400.0000000000000000
40.0000000000000000
25.0000000000000000
12.0000000000000000
[done]
```